Wifi stop working - Chipset Reset Failed
Sometimes, my computer is slow for some seconds and  Wifi suddenly stop working, either not detecting any network or removing the wifi icon
When I hit CTRL + ALT + F3, I see:
Chipset Reset Failed
Unable to reset channel, reset status -22

This errors repeat in several lines, in sequence. I not found a solution googling it. I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I appreciate any help

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Same problem here, think it is a hardware issue.  Ran script from  https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info
